# Using ng-show with a required attribute

Tags: angularjs, html

So is there a way that if I have a HTML 5 'required' attribute on an input, that if that input is not shown due to ng-show not triggering it, that this will not fire the 'required' attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ngRequired](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ng/directive/input) directive.

Although if someone has filled that field out, then changed the form in such a way that it is hidden, the value will still be sent. Using [ngDisabled](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) will get around that. You could still use `ng-show`/`ng-hide` in combination with that of course.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/NWUiXWQO8oZQVZesblFq?p=preview

Comment: if I understand your plunker correctly with ng-required, does it actually rely on another control to dictate its implementation?

Comment: @Mark: do you mean the checkbox? No, I just put that there so you could manually toggle the `isNeeded` property to see the effect on the text box.

Comment: guess I thought with the input having this: ng-disabled="!ctrl.isNeeded" , that it was binding to the checkbox. This said, is there a good frame of reference for displaying error on blur, submit, etc... and then the styling?

Comment: Not bound to the checkbox itself, but rather the `isNeeded` property on the controller... which just so happens to have a binding to the checkbox. But `isNeeded` could by set by any kind of business logic and it would have the same effect on the behaviour of `ng-required` and `ng-disabled` on the text box.

As for showing errors etc, I don't have anything on hand (work mostly back end), but [this post](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html) is probably somewhere I'd start if I were building such a form.